# Issue with Empty SELECT Custom Field in Shopware 6

Tags: custom-fields, shopware6

I’m facing an issue while creating a custom SELECT field in Shopware 6 using a plugin. The custom field is being created successfully, but when I attempt to use the SELECT field in the category settings, the dropdown options appear empty. Instead of showing the expected „ON“ and „OFF“ options, the dropdown displays two empty values.

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyNameSpace;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Context\ActivateContext;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin;
use Shopware\Core\System\CustomField\CustomFieldTypes;
use Shopware\Core\Defaults;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;

class MyClass extends Plugin
{
    public function activate(ActivateContext $activateContext): void
    {
        parent::activate($activateContext);
        
        $context = $activateContext->getContext();
        $this->createCustomField($context);
    }

    private function createCustomField(Context $context): void
    {
        $customFieldRepository = $this->container->get('custom_field_set.repository');

        $customFieldData = [
            'name' => 'categoryNoteSet',
            'config' => [
                'label' => [
                    'en-GB' => 'Categories Notes',
                    'de-DE' => 'Kategorien Hinweise',
                    Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => "Categories Notes"
                ]
            ],
            'relations' => [
                [
                   'entityName' => 'category'
                ]
            ],
            'customFields' => [
                // ... Other custom fields
                [
                    'name' => 'noteOfferActivate',
                    'type' => CustomFieldTypes::SELECT,
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => [
                            'en-GB' => 'Activate Offer note',
                            'de-DE' => 'Angebot Hinweis aktivieren',
                            Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => "Note Text"
                        ],
                        'options' => [
                            [
                                'label' => [
                                    'en-GB' => 'ON',
                                    'de-DE' => 'An',
                                ],
                                'value' => 'true',
                            ],
                            [
                                'label' => [
                                    'en-GB' => 'OFF',
                                    'de-DE' => 'Aus',
                                ],
                                'value' => 'false',
                            ]               
                        ],
                        'customFieldPosition' => 5
                    ]
                ],
                // ... Other custom fields
            ]
        ];

        $customFieldRepository->create([$customFieldData], $context);
    }
}
```

Problem Details:
-I’m creating a custom SELECT field in Shopware 6 using the provided code.
-The custom field creation is successful with two options: „ON“ and „OFF.“
-However, upon accessing category settings, the dropdown field for the SELECT option displays two empty values instead of the expected „ON“ and „OFF“ options.

[that’s how it looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aepOM.png)

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two properties to your `config` array. The documentation isn't very clear on that, but when you create custom fields through the administration user interface, these properties would both be set as well. I verified that the labels indeed appear empty, if those properties are missing.

```php
[
    // ...
    'config' => [
        // ...
        'componentName' => 'sw-single-select',
        'customFieldType' => CustomFieldTypes::SELECT,
    ],
]
```

Comment: Thats it, i missed the componentName, problem solved, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the custom fields are stored as on json field inside the `customFields` column, therefore you have to use the mysql JSON features in order to get the data out of the json in the format you want. Refer to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) for how exactly to do this.

Additionally you should be able to use shopware's built in [Data Abstraction Layer](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/framework/data-abstraction-layer), it will handle the JSON conversion under the hood.